# Why Dig, Curl and Ifconfig gives separate results?

Tags: networking, dns, curl, ifconfig, dig

I hit customer FTP and it gives following IP : 212.18.129.202

My production server has IP:

```
eno16780032: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 146.213.179.131  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 146.213.179.141
```

I use to give this to customer to open and able to Telnet successfully. But customer gets above one. So i tried to debug:

```
[integrator@alp-esb-app01 ~]$ dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
212.18.129.202
[integrator@alp-esb-app01 ~]$ curl ipinfo.io/ip
153.110.241.232
```

Why is Dig and Curl giving separate results?
(Actually i am able to connect to server using FTP but it reset connections when send response back. Not sure why)

Comment: It's unclear how and from where you get these IPs.

Comment: You could try traceroute to both destinations (resolver.opendns.com and ipinfo.io) and check any strange result. #1 suspect: CG-NAT #2: VPN .